# Oracle Apex - OAuth token generated in HTML format

Tags: plsql, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-rest-data-services

On a complete new environment I have created restful services.

**Using PLSQL,** 
Through below code on SQL developer when tried, I received `ORA-20001: Authentication failed.`

```
BEGIN
    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.OAUTH_AUTHENTICATE(
        P_TOKEN_URL     => 'http://<host:ip>/ords/<schema>/oauth/token',
        P_CLIENT_ID     => 'xxxxxxxxxxBaDNGqSq1atg..',
        P_CLIENT_SECRET => 'xxxxxxxxxx5NlSRSoeJrUw..');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(APEX_WEB_SERVICE.OAUTH_GET_LAST_TOKEN);
END;
```

**Using Curl,** 
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -d "client_id=xxxxxxxxxxBaDNGqSq1atg.." -d "client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx5NlSRSoeJrUw.." "http://<host:ip>/ords/<schema>/oauth/token"`

I received html code, And in preview format I got [image]

**Using Postman,** 
I receive below response while generating token.
[image]
[image]

And when saved as html format, I saw below output,
[image]

**FYR,** 
below are the applied settings on ORDS. ORDS was restarted recently.
[image]

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed, there was another port on the same server where idcs has been tested. Thus, the access token URL was redirecting towards the idcs.

After removing the connectivity, we found another issue and reported here, [ORDS: Error 401--Unauthorized From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1: 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499393/ords-error-401-unauthorized-from-rfc-2068-hypertext-transfer-protocol-http)