# ORDS: Error 401--Unauthorized From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1: 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized

Tags: curl, plsql, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-rest-data-services

w.r.t. [Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) : Authentication](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-authentication#oauth2-client-credentials)

And [microservices-the-easy-way-with-ords-and-micronaut-part-1](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/microservices-the-easy-way-with-ords-and-micronaut-part-1)

**Using PLSQL,**
Through below code on SQL developer when tried, I received `ORA-20001: Authentication failed`.

```
BEGIN
    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.OAUTH_AUTHENTICATE(
        P_TOKEN_URL     => 'http://<host:ip>/ords/<schema>/oauth/token',
        P_CLIENT_ID     => 'xxxxxxxxxxBaDNGqSq1atg..',
        P_CLIENT_SECRET => 'xxxxxxxxxx5NlSRSoeJrUw..');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(APEX_WEB_SERVICE.OAUTH_GET_LAST_TOKEN);
END;
```

**Using Curl,**

```
curl -i -k --user xxxxxxxxxxBaDNGqSq1atg..:xxxxxxxxxx5NlSRSoeJrUw.. --data "grant_type=client_credentials" http://<host ip:port>/ords/<schema>/oauth/token
```

I received html code, And in preview format I got
[image]

**Using Postman**
I get the same error in console.
[image]